# How can I get an HTML input converted to PDF at 6x9" or otherwise for KDP paperback creation?

Tags: calibre, file-format, formatting, page-size

I am trying to get from HTML originally intended for Kindle formats, to an output appropriate to KDP paperback format.

Calibre appears to be producing 8 1/2 x 11" output, too large for this service to accept. A little searching has a Library of Babel tinge to the documentation. Doing a "ebook-convert" by itself has three options, one of which looks promising but "ebook-convert --recipes" does not do a standard "List all, or all major, options"

So:

Let's say that I have material in HTML, ePub, or .mobi.

How can I convert this to a PDF file of my own, with a page size of 6x9"?

Thanks,

Comment: What is kdp?......

Comment: KDP = [Amazon Kindle Direct Publishing](https://kdp.amazon.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could install [Prince](https://www.princexml.com/download/) and the [Calibre Prince plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=230027) to generate the .pdf file. You can specify [page sizes](https://www.princexml.com/doc-prince/#page-size) via CSS.